# mySQL - Group 2 rows based on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group rows based on other columns.

This is what the table looks like:

```
| a_id | a_name | b_id | b_name | c_id | c_name | d_id | d_name |
|------|--------|------|--------|------|--------|------|--------|
|   1  | abcdef |   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   2  |   zxy  |   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   3  |  lmao  |   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   1  |   oop  |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   2  | abcdef |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   1  |  nope  |   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   2  | nothing|   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |   1  | abcdef |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |   2  |  oop   |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |   3  | turtles|
```

I want all similar names to be combined into one row. Similarity is determined by a user defined function IS_SAME(str1, str2).

This is what the result should look like.

```
| a_id | a_name | b_id | b_name | c_id | c_name | d_id | d_name |
|------|--------|------|--------|------|--------|------|--------|
|   1  | abcdef |   2  | abcdef |   0  |        |   1  | abcdef |
|   2  |   zxy  |   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   3  |  lmao  |   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   1  |   oop  |   0  |        |   2  |  oop   |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   1  |  nope  |   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   2  | nothing|   0  |        |
|   0  |        |   0  |        |   0  |        |   3  | turtles|
```

I actually have created a query to do this, but I went all Fermat's Last Theorem on it and didn't save the query I used (I saved the previous 5 queries I used for maintaining this list) because I felt it was too simple to record.

Comment: Are we allowed to suggest normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated but doable.  You want to start with a list of names and then join in each table and aggregate on the first column:

```
select max(ta.a_id) as a_id, max(ta.a_name) as a_name,
       max(tb.b_id) as a_id, max(tb.b_name) as b_name,
       max(tc.c_id) as a_id, max(tc.c_name) as c_name,
       max(td.d_id) as a_id, max(td.d_name) as d_name       
from (select a_name as name from table t union select b_name union select c_name union select d_name
     ) names left outer join
     table ta
     on is_same(ta.a_name, names.name) left outer join
     table tb
     on is_same(tb.b_name, names.name) left outer join
     table tc
     on is_same(tc.c_name, names.name) left outer join
     table td
     on is_same(td.d_name, names.name)
group by names.name;
```

Comment: How can I use my IS_SAME() function to compare instead of doing a group which assumes 100% similarity?

Comment: @Nikzilla . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: Oh. Well in that case, I shall test it! Don't code when tired!

Comment: if `group by names.name` there might be duplicate rows due to different names with `is_same(..) = true`. might need to dedupe the result.

Comment: @Fabricator . . . Your question does not seem to have examples of such duplicates.  In any case, the `group by` removes the duplicates and chooses one of the values.  You can use `group_concat()` to get all values within a column.